# Drupal 7 navigation based on URL

Tags: html, drupal-7, navigation, view

Does anyone know if it's possible to extract the URL and if a value is found within the URL to display/hide something?

For instance, if I have a navigation bar that I want to only display for pages that contain 'copier' and I have URL aliases setup, can I setup **Views** module (or something like that) to check the URL for the 'copier' value and if it's found to display the navigation? If so, how would I go about doing that?

I know there can't be duplicate URL aliases but if say I had them as:

node/Copier

node/Copier-training

Could I check that URL and see if copier is present, and if it is display the navigation assoicated with copier?

I'm not really familiar with **Views**.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question or not, the mention of Views is throwing me off a bit, but I believe all you need work with is a Block.  You put your navigation into the Block, and then set the "Visilibity Settings" to be

```
node/*copier*
```

and set "Show block on specific pages" to "Only the listed pages".

This would then show the block on any page with copier in the URL, however this would only work for URLs of the type node/blahblahblah, if you wanted it to also show on say a URL such as blog/copier-training you would have to add another line to the Visibility Settings of the Block

```
node/*copier*
blog/*copier*
```

and also for any subsequent drill-downs also, for instance say blog/richie/copier-training would require

```
node/*copier*
blog/*copier*
blog/richie/*copier*
```

alternatively you could write a whole load of wildcarded options that go as deep as your site URLs may go

```
*/*copier*
*/*/*copier*
*/*/*/*copier*
ad infinitum
```

which is probably better...

If you *do* want to show a View within the Block you can use the following PHP

```
<?php
//load the view by name
$view = views_get_view('sample_view');
//output the view
print views_build_view('embed', $view);
?>
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: With your example of "node/*copier*", would a node like this "node/copier-training" display that block?